# Вывести элементы массива в формате JSON

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

Имеем массив name

```
let name = [
    ['Ободович', 'Иван'],['Булий' , 'Андрей'],['Булий', 'Андрей']
]

let res = name.forEach((elem) => {
let data = Object.create(null, {lastName: {value:''}, firstName: {value:''}) 
data.lastName = elem[0];
data.firstName = elem[1]
})
console.log(res)
```

ожидание

```
res = [
    {lastName:'Ободович', firstName:'Иван'},
    {lastName:'Булий', firstName:'Андрей'},
    {lastName:'Булий', firstName:'Андрей'}
]
```

Comment: Твое "ожидание" не в формате json... https://learn.javascript.ru/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методе **forEach()** ничего не возвращает. Воспользуейтесь методом **map()**

```js
let name = [
  ['Ободович', 'Иван'],
  ['Булий', 'Андрей'],
  ['Булий', 'Андрей']
];

const res = name.map(item => ({
  lastName: item[0],
  firstName: item[1]
}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Все работает. Спс.

Comment: @Виталий Спасибо тут, это галочка слева от ответа, а большое спасибо + голос за ответ :)